# I want to include everything from my main page except one js file ..

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a use case in which i want to include my main.gsp file in my page list.gsp , that is easily achieved by doing

```
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
```

But the problem is that it has jQuery 1.6 version but i want an alternative to that a file called as jquery.js and i when i am including it as well in addition to the main layout its conflicting and creating a problem ..
like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js/jquery', file: 'jquery.js')}"></script>
```

The above is not working , so what i have thought is either manually differentiate the files to be included on my list.gsp page or is there a way to include everything that is on main.gsp page except this jQuery1.6.js file ??

I am open to any other suggestions.. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A dirty method could be to put the script import in a if block that checks for a page property, and in your list.gsp set that property.

In list.gsp:

```
<body fooProperty="1">
```

And in main.gsp:

```
<g:if test="${pageProperty(name:'body.fooProperty) ?: false}">
<%--includes you want for list.gsp here--%>
</g:if>
<g:else>
<%--normal script link -%>
</g:else>
```

Forces a if/else on every single page load you got, but there isnt many other ways to do it. Might be to set a hidden page property and write a loader that overrides the 1.6 import in javascript itself.

Answer (score 0):

Put in your main.gsp

```
${if(!params.jqueryVersion) params.jqueryVersion=''}
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js/jquery', file: 'jquery${params.jqueryVersion)}.js')}"></script>
```

and in your list controller return

```
[myInstancesList:list, jqueryVersion:'-1.4.2']
```